# TabBar in one view leading to a second view with another set of tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I need some help or even a link to direct me to the help will be much appreciated.

I have a main tabBar view now which shows a list of patients in a table as the tabBar default. On clicking of the individual rows of patients in the table it will give me the information of the patients in another view. However, in this patientInfo view, I want to have a new set of tabBar which allows me to show different tabs other that patientInfo.

Is this possible? A tabBarController leading to another tabBarController? I tried but the old tag bars doesnt disappear but instead adds on it, leading to 2 tabBars in one view. I dun wan that =(

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to put your tab bar controller *inside* a navigation controller, and the table view controller inside that tab bar controller, when a row is pressed, you'd push another tab bar controller to the navigation controller.

It'd look like this:

```
Navigation Controller
 |
 ⎬- First Tab Bar Controller
 |  ⎬- Table View Controller
 |  ⎬- ...
 |  ⎬- View Controller
 |
 ⎬- Pushed Tab Bar Controller (pushed when a row is selected)
 |  ⎬- More View Controllers
```

Keep in mind that pushing a tab bar controller when there's another in place can be confusing for the user, as they might not realize or expect that the tabs change too.

To make it clear, I think there's a property on the tab bar controllers that, if on, animates a slide out of the tab bar when the tab bar controller will slide out, and animates a slide in of the tab bar when the controller slides in.
You could use this so the user notices that the tab bar changed.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.. I tried wa u suggested but realized that I cannot put a tab bar controller inside a navigation controller... only the other way round... 

Is there a way around this? Thanks for the help