# replace one tabbar with another on tap, as in iPhoto?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbar

I'm working on a tabbed application using storyboards in Interface Builder.  The Stack Overflow question at [TabBar in one view leading to a second view with another set of tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354005/tabbar-in-one-view-leading-to-a-second-view-with-another-set-of-tabbar) seems to answer or at least be relevant to my question, but unfortunately I don't understand the answer entirely.

The first tab in the UITabBarController takes people to the main/home view controller, which displays a short text on the screen.  I want to add a function whereby the user taps on the screen and a new tab bar slides in (like in iPhoto when you tap on a photo that's been displayed) with options to send, trash, or edit the text.

I don't need the new tab bar to be translucent like it is in iPhoto.

How do I do this?

Comment: NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBar.items];
[items removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[self.tabBar setItems:items];
This code replaces the tab bar items. If this doesn't work tell me in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've decided to deal with the situation a different way.  But if in noodling around I give this a shot I'll let you know.